# Bootstrap: Handle multiple modal dialogs

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to deal with two different modal dialogs within Twitter Bootstrap.

So the idea is that I just copy the modal dialog HTML and create a new button (BTN2) with  `data-toggle="modal2"`. And with a click on the new button (BTN2), the second modal dialog should show up, and not the first one.

I tried it with a click on BTN2 but none of the dialogs showed up. On the existing button (BTN1), however, both dialogs show up.

This is the current modal dialog. Yes it is based on the example provided by bootstrap.com, thus the bs-example-modal-lg class.

```html
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="PodcastModal" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
             <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="list"></ul>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="items"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Done!</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is the button to call the modal dialog.

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> <span class="hidden-xs">Add</span>List</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This questions has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Have you considered the approach of only having one modal?: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `data-toggle` value is not the one responsible for which modal opens, you need the
`data-target` for that. So give each of your modals an `id`, and reference that with
`data-target="#foo"`:

```
<div class="modal" id="modal1"></div>
<div class="modal" id="modal2"></div>

<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal2">
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1">
```

(stripped down to the relevant parts)

Watch out though, if you ever do some meddling with javascript or open a modal from a modal:

> Overlapping modals not supported
>   Be sure not to open a modal while
>   another is still visible. Showing more than one modal at a time
>   requires custom code.

(from the [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals))

Comment: As long as he's not invoking them with JS but doing it this way he shouldn't have that issue. Great answer.

Comment: This works! Thank you. My problem was that I changed the data-toggle of the button to something different than *modal*, b/c I thought it have to be different to the first modal.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe taking a look at this modal example on getbootstrap.com instead will help:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

source: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

There is a `data-target` attribute on the button element that is associated with an `id` of the modal div element.  In this case, `id="myModal"`.  You could create as many modals as you want by using this structure and making sure each button's `data-target` references a unique `id` of a modal.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things, `data-toggle="modal"` and `data-target="#modalId"`

`data-toggle="modal"`: identifies the DOM object having class "modal" and toggles it on the button. Since modals are initially hidden, it just toggles the display and shows the modal dialog.

`data-target="#modalId"`: identifies the DOM object having id "modalId" and targets that for `data-toggle`. This data attribute basically associates the button to the modal popup that needs to be toggled (displayed).

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal"></div>
<div id="modal2" class="modal"></div>
...
...


<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1"></button>
//this will display first modal (modal1)   

<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1"></button>
//this will display second modal (modal2)
```